# yum hangs and won't respond

Tags: linux, centos, yum, centos-5

I am running `yum check-update` and it freezes after a 2 lines of output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
```

I'm not sure what is happening. The last things I remember doing with yum were `yum update` and looking at one of the CentOS yum repos but I didn't make any changes.

Any suggestions to fix yum?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may have a DNS issue. Try to ensure you can resolve DNS records locally:

`nslookup google.com`

If you get an IP back from that command, you should be OK for DNS. Try then removing the fastestmirror cache and re-running your yum command:

`rm -f /var/cache/yum/timedhosts.txt`

Comment: I did get an IP back from that command. timedhosts.txt was an empty text file but I tried removing it anyways. I then reran my yum command. Unfortunately no success. It's still hanging at the same place, "Determining fastest mirrors". If I run verbose, I get      Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Config time: 0.094
Yum Version: 3.2.22
Setting up Package Sacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

Comment: To rule out an issue with the fastestmirror plugin, try running yum without any plugins: `yum --noplugins check-update`

Answer (score 88):

All of this did not work with me.

Using CentOS and yum. yum hangs without an error message, at least, so it appears. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not work (pressing it again and again and again does).

Several things need to be checked:
- are the repositories OK?
- is networking OK?
- are the yum and rpm databases OK?

So, first start with the easy stuff - clean the databases:

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__*
rpm --rebuilddb -v -v   
yum clean all
```

If that did not work, you can set a debug level, error level and timeout for yum in `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
debuglevel=1
errorlevel=1
timeout=1
```

The timeout is standard 30 seconds. So if a repository does not respond, the error takes 30 seconds to appear. Also try using yum without the plugins (like fastest mirror and priorities) with the option `--noplugins`. Now starting yum again should give you more info faster. Test with:

```
yum --verbose --noplugins info
```

You might get something like this:

```
 Config time: 0.105
 Yum Version: 3.2.22
 Setting up Package Sacks
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net link-to-server-repository/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: urlopen error (97, 'Address family not supported by protocol') 
 Trying other mirror.
```

This indicates no information can be received from the server. Try the URL that is displayed by yum (indicated above with link-to-server-repository) in your web browser. Copy&paste it from your yum response, not from this post! If you get a list, you know the repository is online.

If you get an error in your browser, try removing that repository from `/etc/yum.repos.d`. Try to fetch the list on your server with wget and paste the URL:

```
wget link-to-server-repository/repomd.xml
```

If this generates a timeout, then there's a problem with your firewall or proxy settings. Try to disable your firewall.

If you are running `csf` (ConfigServer Security and Firewall) and `lfd` you can disable csf with:

```
csf -x
```

Try yum again and if it works, you'll have to reconfigure your `csf`. Enable `csf` again with:

```
csf -e
```

And also check your proxy settings. You can also try to change the https in to http in the .repo files at `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.

Comment: This answer is worth so much more than 4 upvotes =(

Comment: Lots of good information here.  Increasing the debugging level and running `yum --verbose --noplugins info` led me to find "Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again" which I am investigating now.  My DNS is working so that should not be the problem.

Comment: An important point that seems to be missing in this answer is that `yum check` can take hours to complete! More info: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=46676

Comment: Database cleanup worked for me too

Comment: I had the same issue (yum hanging with no no error message). The solution was to execute `strace yum info`, which showed that yum had a wait on file `/var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock`. After removing this file, yum worked again as expected.

Comment: Trying this solution, I noticed that everything would run fine when using `--noplugins`. After a binary search amongst the plugins, I found that `subscription-manager` was the one causing all the trouble. I disabled it and voilà!

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was a lingering RPM database lock file `/var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock` that made yum commands hang. After removing that file yum could be used again.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. It turned out to be an old DNS address in `resolv.conf`. I changed the IP to the correct one, and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Under Vagrant this can happen too.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue and the reason was the presence of yum lock file `/var/run/yum.pid` where a previous yum run left it because of a fatal error.

I removed it with `sudo rm /var/run/yum.pid` and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't have enough reputation to ask about this comment above:

> Trying this solution, I noticed that everything would run fine when using --noplugins. After a binary search amongst the plugins, I found that subscription-manager was the one causing all the trouble. I disabled it and voilà! – Mariuslp

@mariuslp, I also can only run yum by adding --noplugins. Can you provide more detail as to how you did a "binary search amongst the plugins" and what in that search led you determine what was causing the trouble? Thanks!